# Group price by hour

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have data like this

```
dt                 | price
---------------------------
2016-02-02 12:33:33  3.3
2016-03-02 12:33:33  3.3
2016-02-02 12:03:33  3.3
2016-02-02 12:50:33  3.3
2016-02-02 13:33:33  3.3
```

I need summed price grouped by hour, though I need include year, month and day parts also

desirable result:

```
2016-02-02 12:00:00  9.9
2016-02-02 13:00:00  3.3
2016-03-02 12:00:00  3.3
```

I have query, which gives this result. question is, may be there is more efficient way to do this?

My current query:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS hours, price FROM (
    SELECT substr(dt, 1, 13) AS d, sum(price) as price FROM table
    GROUP BY substr(dt, 1, 13)
) 
ORDER BY hours
```

Comment: Column dt's data type?

Comment: dt's data type is TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select
TRUNC(dt,'HH24'),
sum(price)
from table
group by TRUNC(dt,'HH24')
order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: 'HH24' is more appropriate here

Comment: I tried 'HH24' format after  JohnHC commented, it gives grouped result,   though  not gives hour part, but only day, like this:  `2016-02-02`

Comment: That might be because your Oracle client setting is incorrect. Run `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use to_char:

```
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')||':00:00' as HourBlock, sum(price) as TotalPrice
from MyTable
group by to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')||':00:00'
```

Comment: This gives `ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is || not |` and, if you fix that then `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`. You need to use `||` not `|` and move the concatenation outside the `TO_CHAR` function or just use `TO_CHAR( dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:"00:00"' )`.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, correct on all counts... TBH, the other solution is better XD